# How to prevent kendo grid columns from resizing below a specified width?

Tags: kendo-grid

When I resize the window all the columns become smaller. This is not the behavior I want since some columns are already sized as small as I want them to get from the beginning and I would like them to remain at their starting width while the larger columns shrink.

I tried using the columnResize event to prevent the columns from shrinking below a certain size, however it appears that this event is only for when a user manually resizes a column and it doesn't get fired when the window is resized.

How can I prevent columns from shrinking below a certain size when the window is resized?

(I am using the javascript version of the grid.)

Answer (score 0):

In column definition `columns` in `Grid` configuration you can set attribute `width`. This force size of this column and prevent auto resizing during window resize.

If you don't set this option, column would dynamically fit into space.

```
{
    field: "ColumnName",
    title: "Column",
    width: 120
}
```

Comment: Thanks suvroc, but I think you must be mistaken because I already have specified the widths and it does resize the columns when I resize the window. I actually tried taking the width off to see what would happen and the grid gets reaaaallly messed up when I do that so I have to specify them.

Comment: Check example in Kendo documentation: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.width This shows how it works. Maybe write your column configuration.

Comment: I think my problem probably has to do with the templates I'm using for the columns... will have to do some more investigation to find out though.

Comment: Without your code to column configuration, this is all I can help you.

Comment: I know... I plan to edit my post with more info as soon as I get a chance to get back to this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Please find the solutions below

```
 <script>
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
      { field: "name" },
      { field: "age" }
    ],
    dataSource: [
      { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
    ],
    resizable: true,
    columnResize: function(e) {
      $("#grid colgroup col").each(function () {
        if ($(this).width() < 50) {
          $(this).css("width", "50px");
        }
      })
    }
  });
</script>
```

Please find the [Fiddle](http://dojo.telerik.com/eNITI/2) for a working demo

Another way of it doing it is mentioned [here](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/apply-minimum-column-width-during-column-resize)

Comment: Thanks. This is strange though because even without the columnResize function your example works the way I want mine to work. However, mine still allows the  column to get too small even with the columnResize function. In my code, columnResize is only fired when when the user resizes a column but not when the window is resized. Maybe this is a newer version of the controls than I'm using... I'll have to find out what the difference is.